# JQuery to Get the count

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

[image]

How could I get the count or length of all the **option** using jquery

Comment: You should look into `Stack Overflow` for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152738/counting-the-number-of-options-tag-in-the-select-dom-element-in-jquery AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337749/how-do-i-check-how-many-options-there-are-in-a-dropdown-menu are good examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple

```
var count = $('#ID_of_dropdown > option').length;
```

or

```
var count = $("#ID_of_dropdown option").length
```